# Dividir números de um int. C++

Tags: c++

Ola!
Estou lendo e estudando sobre C++ no livro " C ++ Como Programar 5ª edição ".
Há uma questão na pg 97. Questão 2.28 cujo eu não consigo realizar, sendo ela:

Escreva um programa que insere um inteiro de cinco dígitos, separa o inteiro em seus dígitos individuais e imprime os dígitos separados
entre si por três espaços cada. [Dica: Utilize operadores de divisão de inteiros e módulo.] Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar 42339, o
programa deve imprimir:
4 2 3 3 9.

Pelo que eu compreendi, devo fazer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

int x ;
cin >> x; // Digitar cinco números

// eu não faço ideia como separar estes números?
// alguém pede me ajudar? 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No seu próprio texto tem:

> *"Dica: Utilize operadores de divisão de inteiros e módulo"*.

Essa é mesmo a dica. Suponha que você leia o número inteiro `42339`, como você mesmo ilustra.

Se você dividir ele por 10, dá quanto?

```
42339 / 10 = 4233,9
```

Repare como a vírgula separa o primeiro dígito à direita (não por acaso, a dezena) do seu número original. Em C++, você pode pegar esses valores fazendo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int num = 42339;

    int dig = num % 10; // módulo (resto da divisão) por 10
    int sobra = int(num / 10); // divisão inteira por 10

    cout << "num: " << num << " dig: " << dig << " sobra: " << sobra << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado é esse (veja funcionando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/neJ26p)):

```
num: 42339 dig: 9 sobra: 4233
```

Ou seja, pra fazer *um passo* do que você precisa, basta aplicar essa regra (use o módulo - isto é, resto da divisão - por 10 para pegar o dígito, e a divisão inteira para manter o que sobra). Então, repita esse procedimento para os demais passos, até que o seu resultado da divisão inteira seja 0 (não há mais nada sobrando e você já processou todos os dígitos).